# How to calculate the maximum median in an array

Tags: algorithm, math, median

This is an algorithm question:

Input is an array with non-duplicate positive integers. Find a continuous subarray(size > 1) which has the maximum median value.

Example: input: [100, 1, 99, 2, 1000], output should be the result of (1000 + 2) / 2 = 501

I can come up the brute force solution: try all lengths from 2 -> array size to find the maximum median. But it seems too slow. I also tried to use two pointer on this question but not sure when to move left and right pointer.

Anyone has a better idea to solve this question?

Comment: Can you provide an example? From what I understand, taking a subarray of length 2 containing the maximum element would be enough, but maybe it is more intricate than I think.

Comment: Doing some tests with the brute force algorithm, it seems like it's always arrays of 2 or 3, not necessarily containing the maximum element. But there may be some exceptions... Example: Array = [4, 5, 6, 1, 9, 2, 3, 8, 0, 7], Maximum-median subarray: [8, 0, 7], Median: 7.

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé. Just added an example. What you found is really interesting. I haven't implemented to brute force yet, but I tried many examples looks like the size is always less than 3. Not sure if there is a way to prove this?

Comment: I've put my brute force implementation as a answer (to be improved) so you can test and develop your intuition.

Comment: Just to be clear, is it the **median** or **mean** value you are looking for? The question mentions "median", but the example is the calculated "mean" value.

Comment: @AndersLindahl, it is the mean value. As the subarray's size needs to be greater than 1, so in the example, I picked [2, 1000]. The median of [2, 1000] is (2 + 1000) / 2 = 501. Does my explanation make sense to you?

Comment: @Anders: given two numbers, their mean and median always coincide.

Comment: You can bring this down to `O(N^2logN)` using the two-heaps running medians thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tl;dr - We can show that the answer must be of length 2 or 3, after which it's linear time to check all the possibilities.

Let's say the input is `A` and the smallest subarray with the biggest median is `a`. The biggest median is either a single element or the average of a pair of elements from `a`. Notice that every element in `a` bigger than the largest element of the median can only be next to elements less than the smallest element of the median (otherwise such a pair could be chosen as a subarray to form a bigger median).

If either end of `a` had a pair of elements that didn't include an element of the median, it could be eliminated from `a` without affecting the median, a contradiction.

If either end of `a` was smaller than the smallest element of the median, eliminating it would increase the median, a contradiction.

Thus each end of `a` is either an element of the median or larger than the largest element of the median (because it's larger than the smallest elt of the median and not equal to the largest elt of the median).

Thus each end of `a` is an element of the median because otherwise, we'd have an element larger than an element of the median adjacent to an elt of the median, forming a larger median.

If `a` is odd then it must be of length three, since any larger odd length could have 2 removed from the end of `a` farthest from the median without changing the median.

If `a` is even then it must be of length 2 because any larger even length bookended by the elements of the median with interior elements alternating between smaller and larger than the median must have one of the median elements adjacent to a larger element than the other elt of the median, forming a larger median.

This proof outline could use some editing, but regardless, the conclusion is that the smallest array containing the largest median must be of length 2 or 3.

Given that, check every such subarray in linear time. O(n).

Comment: Here's your proof simplified. Pick a subarray. If its first two elements are both not smaller than its median, keep them as the new subarray. Otherwise, remove both and keep the rest. Repeat unti the length is 2 or 3.

Comment: Picking exactly two elements is not essential. You xan divide the subarray in half and keep the half with the larger median. If they are equal keep either. BTW the same logic works for the arithmetic mean.

Comment: @n.m. [1,5,3,1] has a median of 2. The first 2 elts are not both smaller than the median, removing them leavs us with [3,1] with a median of 2, but optimal is [5,3] with a median of 4.

Comment: This procedure is not guaranteed to arrive at the maximal median, It is a **proof** that the shortest subarray with the maximal median cannot be longer than 3 elements.In your example, (1,5,3,1) is not the shortest subarray with the maximal median because after removing (1,5) we are left with (3,1) which is a shorter one with the same median.

Comment: @n.m. All you've given is a process for reducing a long array to a 2-3 element subarray, but your procedure has nothing to do with finding the max median, so doesn't prove that the max median can be found in such a 2-3 elt subarray. That happens to be true, but this doesn't prove it.

Comment: It does prove it by contradiction (assume the shortest subarray with the maximal median is longer than 3 elements, demonstrate that a shorter subarray with the same or larger median exists, a contradiction). Each step reduces the length without decreasing the median. Your proof does exactly the same, but is more convoluted.

Comment: @n.m. [1,3,2,4] has a median of 2.5. The first two elements are not both smaller than the median, so our new subarray is [1,3] which has a median of 2,  which is smaller.

Comment: Not "not both smaller"  but "both not smaller" i.e. both larger or equal. Sorry bad wording on my part.

Comment: @n.m. [4,3,1,5] median is 3.5. It is not true that both of the first 2 are >= the median so we are left with [1,5] which has a median of 3.

Comment: I think there's an error in my proof for even-length arrays. Can be fixed as in my second comment. Instead of looking at the two elements individually, look at their median. If it's greater or equal than the original median, keep the two as the new subarray, otherwise discard them.

Comment: Your example is exactly the case where my proof has an error, namely when the two elements are in the middle of the sorted array. But the fixed proof works.

Comment: @n.m. Now I think you're right, but it isn't a proof until you can show why this process never reduces the median.

Comment: It's because of this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1801836/relationship-between-subset-medians-and-the-median The median of two parts cannot be both smaller than the median of their union so it is always possible to reduce the size without reducing the median.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Python implementation of an algorithm that solves the problem in `O(n)`:

```py
import random
import statistics

n = 50
numbers = random.sample(range(n),n)

max_m = 0;
max_a = [];

for i in range(2,3):
    for j in range(0,n-i+1):
        a = numbers[j:j+i]
        m = statistics.median(a)
        if m > max_m:
            max_m = m
            max_a = a

print(numbers)
print(max_m)
print(max_a)
```

This is a variation of the brute force algorithm (O(n^3)) that performs only the search for sub-arrays of length 2 or 3. The reason is that for every array of size `n`, there exists a sub-array that has the same or improved median. Applying this reasoning recursively, we can reduce the size of the sub-array to 2 or 3. Thus, by looking only at sub-arrays of size 2 or 3, we are guaranteed to obtain the sub-array with the maximum median.

The operation is the following: If, for a contiguous sub-array (at the beginning or at the end), at least half of the elements are lower than the median (or lower than both values forming the median, if this is the case), remove them to improve or at least preserve the median.

If in all sub-arrays there is always at least one more element above or equal to the median(s) than below, there will come a point where the size of the sub-array will be that of the median. In that case, it means that the complement will have more elements below the median, and thus, we can simply remove the complement and improve (or preserve) the median. Thus, we can always perform the operation. For `n=3`, it can happen that you need to remove 2 or 3 elements to perform the operation, which is not allowed. In this case, the result is the list itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The time complexity should be greater than O(n^2) as statistics.median(a) should take more than O(N). Not sure if proof by contradiction can prove that answer's length should alway be 2 or 3.

Comment: @CipherText There is an algorithm to find the median in an average of `O(n)`: https://rcoh.me/posts/linear-time-median-finding/ . Since we don't need the whole array to be sorted, some optimization can be done. However, I'm not sure about the implementation used in Python statistics

Comment: Yep. I know quick select can be O(N) in average. But `for i in range(2,n):` is O(N), `for j in range(0,n-i+1):` is another O(N), `m = statistics.median(a)` is O(N) too. So the total should be roughly O(N^3). Any way, I think your idea of length of 2 or 3 is correct even though I cannot find a mathematical way to prove it either. Thanks for you answer!

Comment: Oh, you are right about `O(n^3)`. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I edited my answer with the proof for list of 2 or 3 and the algorithm in O(n)

Comment: I'm not sure your proof makes sense. By definition each subarray will have the same number of elements above and below the median.

Comment: @Dave I did not formulated it correctly. I really meant "above or equal to the median", so the array is not split in half exactly.